# Error: spawn cmd ENOENT in create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I installed nodejs and after then when I try to run my previous react app by running `yarn start` it gives me an error something like this.

Even if I make a new app with create-react-app it gives the same error while trying to start.

nodejs apps are working fine so I think the problem is with create-react-app.  I don't know how to fix them.

```
$ react-scripts start
Starting the development server...

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

And I have no idea what is wrong. Please help me fix this.

Comment: silly question probably but what directory are you in when you're running the start command? are you in the server directory but the start command lives in the client directory?

Comment: I am in the client directory. I am 100% sure about where I need to run `yarn start`. In fact, I created a new app with `create-react-app` and cd into the directory and still, it gives me the same error.

Comment: try downgrading react-scripts according to this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7061 to version : "react-scripts": "^2.1.8"

Comment: Do I need to do this every time ? I mean whenever i will use  create-react-app. I have to downgrade react-script to 2.1.8

Comment: Is there any other way to fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

Change react-scripts version in package.json to 2.1.8. It works for me.

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.